# Windows search results background color white when in dark mode

Tags: colors

From the desktop, when using 'Win S' to search for anything the results background is white. I'm running Windows v1903 18362.267 and have set my desktop to use Dark mode through 'Settings/Colors/Choose your colour'. I would expect this background to be a darker colour when it appears its really bright and stark against the dark theme.

Anyone know of a setting, registry perhaps, to change this colour?